# iPhone Swift Changing your initial Scene

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, sprite-kit

Now, I know how to transition scenes in SpriteKit games. The tricky thing I can't wrap my brain around is changing the initial one that is loaded. My game I have created jumps straight into the game. That initial scene is called GameScene.swift. I created a MainMenuScene.swift and I am trying to change it to load that first instead. Then once clicked I'll do an SKTransition to the next scene just as I have working later in the game.

This is my view Controller code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        //skView.showsFPS = true
        //skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

I thought changing the "GameScene" to "MainMenuScene" would do the trick but nothing gets loaded at all. Then I thought maybe it was the size but that all gets the same setting as the other Scene. Even trying to add the Node count, nothing shows up. So I am assuming nothing is being loaded at all. Maybe I am blind and stupid but I just can't see it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your viewController like this:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

           override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                let scene = MainMenuScene(size: view.bounds.size) //This can be any scene you want the game to load first
                let skView = self.view as! SKView
                skView.showsFPS = false
                skView.showsNodeCount = false
                skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
                scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
                skView.presentScene(scene)
        }

    }
```

In your MainMenuScene.swift (and every other scene you want included in your game) make sure that the class itself starts like this:

```
class chooseScene: SKScene {

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

} }
```

This is the code I have used in my viewController and SKScenes and I had the exact same problem as you a few months ago.

Comment: Just to note: In my code I used .ResizeFill. Yours may need to be .AspectFill depending on your game. Just incase you didn't know this stuff anyway here's a good explanation: http://www.thinkingswiftly.com/positioning-sksprites-in-spritekit-with-skscene-scalemode/

Answer (score 0):

in your viewcontroller try this

```
// Configure the view.
let skView = self.view as! SKView
skView.showsFPS = true
skView.showsNodeCount = true

/* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

let scene = MainMenuScene(size: skView.frame.size)

/* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

skView.presentScene(scene)
```

in **MainMenuScene**, make sure you add these initializers

```
override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Comment: I have the init stuff in the MainMenuScene. When I added your line for let scene = MainMenu.... it loads the Menu as it should. But the thing that gets fishy, is that the GameScene doesn't load anything as it's supposed to. It'll run the timer and the game logic will run it out, switch to the end game scene. Then when you switch back, it'll repeat the same thing again. Is there something I'd need to change in the GameScene(the original initial scene)?

Comment: i have no idea what's going on.  not sure how GameScene even comes into the picture from MainMenuScene.  Can't see your code.. you know?  I'm just letting you know how to load one scene vs another in the view controller.

Comment: I have most of the game logic get called in the didMoveToView. The first thing is the background color gets changed. That works. Then none of the labels directly after get put on the screen. Should I be structuring this differently now that it isn't the initial one?

Comment: Could the screens parameters and such be getting messed up? That would explain how the background and everything else is still working. How would I adjust it so it was the same as I was initially doing it?